# C - printf - remove leading zeroes

Tags: c, printf

When I use printf like this:

```
printf("%.*ju ", size_length, (uintmax_t) thing->fts_statp->st_size);
```

It adds leading zeroes to make `thing->fts_statp->st_size` the length `size_length` (which is somewhat acceptable because its the right size, but visually unappealing). Is there a way to print size information with printf that doesn't do this?

EDIT for more information:

Currently it prints like this:

```
00012

00234

51234

01203

00001
```

I'd like it to print

```
   12

  234

51234

 1203

    1
```

Comment: Perhaps you could consider showing an example of what it currently looks like and also what you want it to look like. Otherwise any answers you get can be skewed by others' interpretations of your description, which doesn't always work out even when the description is clear.

Comment: @mah just edited it, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Isn't a leading 0 an octal representation in C?

Comment: @user3121023 worked perfectly, does `.` only affect the cases with number types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want space padding:

```
printf("% *ju ", size_length, (uintmax_t) thing->fts_statp->st_size);
```